# Is it possible to automate s2s configuration / s2s fields mapping?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

Is it possible to make it in apex?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no SOAP, REST, Tooling, or Metadata object that represents a field mapping for S2S, so we must conclude that the only way to perform mapping is manually, by hand, or writing a script for Selenium or some other technique that controls the browser directly.